# Read snappy compressed files in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, snappy

I have .txt.snappy files emitted by Structured Streaming, and I have a batch pipeline which runs Hadoop and needs to read these files.
Can someone help me if this is possible and with a short code snippet?

```
  @Override
  public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Arguments arguments = SimpleArgParser.parse(args, Arguments.class);
    JobConf conf = new JobConf(getConf(), TestMapper.class);

    conf.setJobName("TestMapper");
    conf.set(
        "io.compression.codecs",
        "org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DefaultCodec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec");
    conf.setBoolean("hadoop.native.lib", true);
    conf.setInt("io.compression.codec.snappy.buffersize", 65536);

    conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    conf.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    conf.setMapperClass(Map.class);
    conf.setNumReduceTasks(0);

    conf.setInputFormat(SequenceFileInputFormat.class);
    conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(arguments.outputPath));
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(conf, new Path(arguments.inputPath));

    JobClient.runJob(conf);
    return 0;
  }
```

I have put the files in HDFS and checked with :

```
hadoop fs -text /var/log/icarus.txt.snappy
```

It actually is readable.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why bother with mapreduce if you're already using Spark, which can also read Sequence files?

Comment: @OneCricketeer : because of legacy reasons, the batch pipeline is in Hadoop.

Comment: Spark can also do batch... But yes, MapReduce can read Snappy data. Did you try it?